# Can't I run file in temporary folder using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I was trying to using this code below...

```
**subprocess.Popen('%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\AdobeARM - Copy.log').communicate()**
```

but I got an error message.
Is there anyone can help this?

Comment: can you edit your question to show the error message? I suspect that' s a problem of non-interpretation of `USERPROFILE` env variable, but still, if you have the information, why not provide it?

Comment: Do we have to guess what error message you got?  "an error message" does not help us in any way.

Comment: @cdarke: fortunately I know the problem, but annoying still... Doesn't help the quality of the questions on the site for future readers. Think about them!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 
I'm sorry to make you annoying.

Comment: @cdarke
You are right...It was my fault.
I'm sorry about that

Comment: @everline:  its OK, but please, if you post a problem here again include the full error message, including the trace.

Comment: @cdarke 
alright :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's an environment variable in the path you can add `shell=True` to force running a batch process which will evaluate env. vars:

```
subprocess.Popen('"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\AdobeARM - Copy.log"',shell=True).communicate()
```

Note the protection with quotes since there are spaces. You can also drop the quotes if you pass a list containing one element to `Popen`, which is cleaner:

```
subprocess.Popen(['%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\AdobeARM - Copy.log'],shell=True).communicate()
```

alternately if you just want to activate the default editor for your logfile, there's a simpler way (which does not block the executing script, so it's slightly different):

```
p = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'),r"AppData\Local\Temp\AdobeARM - Copy.log")
os.startfile(p)
```

Maybe it can be even simpler since that may be the temporary directory you're trying to reach:

```
p = os.path.join(os.getenv('TEMP'),r"AdobeARM - Copy.log")
os.startfile(p)
```

Comment: if file is not on use (mean lock)!

Comment: of course file must be free of any write lock. But the first message (undisclosed by the OP, bad question) is because `Popen` interprets `%USERPROFILE%` literally.

Comment: don't use `%` characters with `os.getenv()`, those are only for cmd, it should be `os.getenv("USERPROFILE")` and `os.getenv("TEMP")`.

Comment: @mata: of course! I wrote that without testing it. Fixed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre
Thank you for helping me a lot.
appologize for my bad question.